# Is there a way to disable waterline and use a different ORM in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, sails.js, waterline

I'd like to replace waterline with mongoose in my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) application. I'm looking for the correct way to do this, but I don't see how in the documentation. Can anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Defining overrides via .sailsrc

You could do this via config overrides, to be defined via `.sailsrc` in your project root. Basically you have to prevent the entire Waterline initialization, currently tagged as `orm` hook. In .sailsrc:

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "orm": false,
    "pubsub": false
  }
}
```

You'll have to disable the `pubsub` hook as well - it depends on the `orm` hook. Relevant lines in the source: [v0.10](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/df63646464f21ad697bf9ad72506ce4ef0ab9ffb/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js#L47), [v0.9.8](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/c25157902633c28c6e5ae1fc593f1717dd932242/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js#L47).

This will switch off the `orm` hook for the following start commands:

- sails lift
- sails console
- node app.js (since [commit 862c053a66](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-new/commit/862c053a663867615383265b6d3aebfaf5bec84b)), see "Making app.js use .sailsrc" for older versions

Concerning the stability of this in future versions of Sails you should be aware of the fact that the hook system currently is tagged as unstable and disabling hooks is [advised against](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/c25157902633c28c6e5ae1fc593f1717dd932242/lib/app/load.js#L141):

```
// Allow disabling of hooks by setting them to "false"
// Mostly useful for testing, and may cause instability in production!
```

Additional information can be found here:

- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/issues/69
- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1077

### Making app.js use .sailsrc

**Note**: This is baked into Sails by default since the discussed PR was merged for bleeding edge git checkouts.

**For Sails 0.10.x**

To make .sailsrc apply to app.js you could replace line 37 in app.js with this:

```
// app.js, following line 36
var fs = require('fs');
var sailsRc = __dirname + '/.sailsrc';
var config = {};

fs.exists(sailsRc, function(exists){
   if (!exists) return sails.lift();

   fs.readFile(sailsRc, 'utf8', function(err, data){
     if (err) {
       console.warn('Error while reading .sailsrc:' + err);
     }

     try {
       config = JSON.parse(data);
     } catch(e) {
       console.warn('Error while parsing .sailsrc:' + err);
     }

     sails.lift(config);
   });
});
```

**For Sails 0.9.x**

Replace app.js with this:

```
// Start sails and pass it command line arguments
var fs = require('fs'),
    optimist = require('optimist'),
    sails = require('sails');

var sailsRc = __dirname + '/.sailsrc';
var config = optimist.argv;

fs.exists(sailsRc, function(exists){
  if (!exists) return sails.lift(config);

  fs.readFile(sailsRc, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.warn('Error while reading .sailsrc:' + err);
    }

    try {
      config = sails.util.merge(config, JSON.parse(data));
    } catch(e) {
      console.warn('Error while parsing .sailsrc:' + err);
    }

    sails.lift(config);
 });
});
```

Comment: I use the version 0.9.8 and my app.js is almsot empty excpt `require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);` but I found a way to start sails lift instead of app.js https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvT0VITW0wSHlnMG8

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned this applies to the v0.10 and the current master branch. Updated my answer accordingly and looking into the options for this on 0.9.x.

Comment: By the way, I couldn't make it work with nodemon (unable to run sails lift from nodemon, reference issue). ANd there should not be any comment into the `.sailsrc` file.

Comment: I use comments in the first line in code blocks to jot down the path this file should reside in. Anyway, I removed the comment for the .sailsrc block. Concerning your nodemon issue I'd say this is a topic for a seperate question.

Comment: @Vadorequest Any luck with the code block under "For Sails 0.9.x"?

Comment: Works. If you could add a link about `pubsub` doc or something, would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Added links to the relevant lines in the sails source.

Comment: fantastic overview- more info on disabling hooks here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1077#issuecomment-28074836

Comment: Thanks @mikermcneil. I updated the answer to reflect the the landed PR and added the link to Sails issue 1077.