# Sails.js - Is it possible to 'turn off' waterline module completly or instead of using sails-mongo use mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, sails.js, waterline

I created project with 'express' and 'mongoose' framework an year ago.

Currently I try to migrate this project into Sails.js.

Everything is really fine, except of migrate 'mongoose' to 'waterline'.

I don`t need waterline ORM, just want to use mongoose, it is enough for me.

Q: Is it possible to get rid waterline from Sails.js and instead of this use 'mongoose' module?

Comment: Looks to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505674/is-there-a-way-to-disable-waterline-in-sails-js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is working, but there is a [sails-mongoose adapter](https://github.com/ktkaushik/sails-mongoose)