# How can I use Sails.js without Waterline?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I tried out Sails v10 beta and liked associations in Waterline.

However, I would like to try out the Sails framework using the native MongoDB driver sans any ORM. Is there any easy way to do this? Or are Waterline and Sails.js tightly coupled together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable waterline in sails.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505674/is-there-a-way-to-disable-waterline-in-sails-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Waterline and Sails.js are tightly coupled together. But...

You can still use native MongoDB driver (just like any other module) with Sails.js. In order to do so:

1. Don't create / generate any Sails.js models (otherwise they'll be autoloaded).
2. `npm install --save mongodb` to install the native driver and add it to `package.json`.
3. `require('mongodb')` in your controller and off you go.